# What is the determining factor between two potential bond candidates?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, bond, hydrogen-bond

Say you have a vacuum (imaginary, of course) with three hydrogen atoms, how do we determine which two will bond and which one will be left out? If the same energy is present (equally) for the entire reaction, is the priority given strictly to the two that are closer to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the collision has too much energy. or if energy released by the bond formation is not dissipated by photon emission, collision, or vibration energy, then the bond is broken again. Similarly, $\ce{2 H}$ need it too to form $\ce{H2}$.

As a mechanical, everyday analogy, imagine a marble play with frictionless terrain, balls and a round enough hole. If you push a ball, it would not end in the (empty) hole, but will escape on the other side. It has to lose some energy somehow, not to be able to escape.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this is good information, but it doesn't answer my entire concern. I have rephrased my question — made it simpler, in case you have anything else to add.

Comment: As there are quantum effects, we cannot determine it, even if we knew exactly their state. // It is like this: 3 equally good wild west gunners randomly shoot to each other. Each shot has probability of kill  0.2. Which of those 3 survive ?